# Why do torches light up underwater?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was messing around in the caves when I realized how dark it was. I placed down some torches, and then realized where they were.[image]

How did these torches end up in the water?

Comment: This must be Terraria Mobile Only. In the Desktop version at best they light up when dropped, but can not be placed in water, and water will knock them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can take torches anywhere. Perhaps there should be a feature that puts out a fire if you have it underwater. It would just change to a "stick" then.